# Как получить массив из отдельных элементов многоуровневого массива Js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив:

```
[
{name: "Test", arge: 23},
{name: "Test1", arge: 25},
{name: "Test2", arge: 33},
]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу получить массив из всех значений name.
То есть: `arr=["Test","Test1","Test2"]`

Comment: Вы знаете циклы?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "Знаете ли вы украинскую ночь? Нет, вы не знаете украинской ночи."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const input = [
    {name: "Test", arge: 23},
    {name: "Test1", arge: 25},
    {name: "Test2", arge: 33},
];

const arr = input.map(e => e.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Полностью согласен с ответом @hlearn

Но, возможно, вы не понимаете что именно происходит во время выполнения этого кода.
Возможно, вам станет понятнее, если взглянете на вариант с циклом. Но суть алгоритма везде одинаковая: поочередно обращаемся к каждому элементу массива (каждый элемент в нем это объект) и просто получаем свойство этого объекта, записывая как и куда хотим.

```js
const input = [
    {name: "Test", arge: 23},
    {name: "Test1", arge: 25},
    {name: "Test2", arge: 33},
];
const result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    result.push(input[i].name);
}

console.log(result);
```